# C# Best way of assigning values to strings in a loop

Tags: c#, .net, performance, string, loops

I wonder what is the most efficient way of assigning string variables in a loop. So, for example if I have to browse through a list of nodes and assigning the value of the node to a string, would it be better if I define a variable before the loop starts like

```
string myStringVariable = string.Empty
foreach(XmlNode node in givenNodes)
{
    myStringVariable = node.Value;
    ....
    ...
}
```

or would it be more efficient if I define the variable inside the loop like

```
foreach(XmlNode node in givenNodes)
{
    string myStringVariable = node.Value;
    ....
    ...
}
```

I think the first approach is more efficient while the second looks more elegant. Is there a performance difference between the two?

Thanks for you answers.

Comment: Maybe you can format the source code parts in your question. Mark it and use 'Ctrl + K' or the code sample button.

Answer (score 13):

With modern compilers this doesn't make any performance difference at all and you should always use the way that best matches your algorithm. That is, prefer the second variant if you don't need the variable's value from the last iteration.

Comment: Sorry, you seem to be right in fact! (Down-vote removed) I have a tendency always to forget about compiler optimisations...

Answer (score 6):

I guess the main question is: do you need to use that string variable further down in your code somewhere, or is its use limited to the scope of the for loop? If it's limited to the scope of the for loop, definitely declare it inside the loop. I doubt there's any performance penalty for doing it either way, but that should be secondary to keeping your variables scoped properly.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no real performance difference between the two.  The VM will recognize that it only needs to allocate space on the stack for one additional variable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't usually optimize to this level, because I'd expect the JIT compiler to be able to perform an optimization like that anyway at runtime. That being said, I've never actually compared the two. Of course, if you really do need the maximum performance, it's worth testing it both ways (using a sufficent number of iterations and with a release build).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set up a little test in a console application and test it.
I get very close results for both methods.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace stringtestloop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch();
            int itterations = 1024 * 1024 * 512;

            w.Start();
            string var1 = string.Empty;
            for (var i = 0; i < itterations; i++)
            {
                var1 = "some string";
            }
            w.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("outside: {0} ms", w.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            w.Reset();

            w.Start();
            for (var i = 0; i < itterations; i++)
            {
                string var2 = "some string";
            }
            w.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("inside: {0} ms", w.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

The next question to ask yourself is... Is 536870912 (1024*1024*512) a similar number to what you are going to be working with. If not, if your number is going to be a lot less, then you really aren't going to notice the difference.

Comment: Cheers Greg,

I do see a performance difference using your code. When declared outside it is taking approx 1500 ms, when inside it is taking approx 2000ms.

Comment: You may want to double check the benchmarking, Hamid. Like Greg, I get very similar results. Also, note that if you compile this release, it optimizes the loop body away.

Answer (score 1):

Due to fact, that strings are immutable and .net works with references, there is no performance difference between both methods.

Maybe the first one would be a little bit slower, cause there is one (unneeded) set of myStringVariable to string.Empty. But i think these issues will be kept by compiler and JIT and so there is no difference between both in case of performance.

Last but not least there is a difference in scope. So declare the variable in the appropriate scope, where the variable is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is any significant performance difference, since in both cases you're just getting a reference to the XmlNode.Value, not creating a new string.

Still, you usually shouldn't worry about optimizing these cases. Just declare the variable in the scope it's going to be used and let the compiler work its magic.